# Add Text ONLY on LAST PAGE of Advance PDF template in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I want to add some text (e.g. This is Computer Generated Bill) **ONLY on LAST PAGE** of **Advanced PDF template in Netsuite**; where content of page ends . Problem is as number of pages change, text occur on all pages or change its position. Unable to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing the xml of the freemarker template you can add a custom block of code as the last thing on the page. If you need to make it prominent you can center it and add a bunch of padding above it.